# Golang преобразовать дату формата Y-m-d H:i:s в тип time.Time

Tags: golang

Использую библиотеку [gorilla/feeds](https://github.com/gorilla/feeds) для генерации `RSS` и `Atom`

Я нахожусь в самом начале пути изучения языка `go` и возник глупый вопрос.

В `feeds.Item` передается дата `time.Now()`, вывожу

```
now := time.Now()
fmt.Println(now)
```

получаю текущую дату формата

```
2016-09-08 22:16:11.578190956 +0700 +07
```

библиотека `gorilla/feeds` в свою очередь на выходе отдает

```
<pubDate>Thu, 08 Sep 2016 22:16:11 +0700</pubDate>
```

Вопрос:
Как правилько скормить кастомную дату формата `Y-m-d H:i:s` (строка) в `feeds.Item.Created`

Текущая реализация

```
posts := new(Blog)
getJson("http://domain.com/api/v1/blog", posts)
now := time.Now()
feed := &feeds.Feed{
    Title:       "Project Blog",
    Link:        &feeds.Link{Href: "https://domain.com/blog"},
    Description: "Domestic and International shipping discussion",
    Author:      &feeds.Author{Name: "test", Email: "test@test.com"},
    Created:     now,
}

feed.Items = []*feeds.Item{}
for _, post := range posts.Records {
    feedItem := &feeds.Item{
        Title:       post.Title,
        Link:        &feeds.Link{Href: post.Link},
        Description: post.Body,
        Author:      &feeds.Author{Name: post.AuthorName, Email: post.AuthorEmail},
        Created:     post.Date,
    }
    feed.Items = append(feed.Items, feedItem)
}
```

Ошибка

> cannot use post.Date (type string) as type time.Time in field value

Comment: [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse)?

Comment: гугление приводит к использованию этого метода вида `time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04", "2011-01-19 22:15")`, мне кажется это немного не то

Comment: И почему же не то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
Отдал в JSON дату формата `RFC3339`

Через `time.Parse` привел данные к нужному типу

```
created, e := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, post.Date)
if e != nil {
     log.Fatal(e)
}
```

Спасибо пользователю **D-side** за наводку :)